# Object of type Publisher is not JSON serializable in Django Multiple Pagination

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pagination, drf-queryset

I have tried DjangoRestMultipleModels Pagination from [here](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pagination.html), Now I'm facing JSON serializable error!

**Views.py**

```
from drf_multiple_model.views import ObjectMultipleModelAPIView
from drf_multiple_model.pagination import MultipleModelLimitOffsetPagination

class LimitPagination(MultipleModelLimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 2


class MultiplePagination(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    pagination_class = LimitPagination
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        querylist = (
            {'queryset': Publisher.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PublisherSerializer},
            {'queryset': Book.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': BookSerializer},
        )
        return Response(querylist, status=200)
```

This is the error I am facing...

[image: This is the error.]

Comment: use a JsonResponse

Comment: @SachinYadav I have tried this option. When I use JsonResponse(querylist), it shows to use safe=False parameter, then I used JsonResponse(querylist, safe=False), it shows "Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable" error!!